# Is this theorem concerning the change of bases and my proof thereof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, change-of-basis

I seek verification of my proof for this change of bases theorem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The theorem is stated below:

> Let $V, W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$.
>
> Let $T: V\to W$ be a linear mapping.
>
> Let $B_{0}, B_{1}$ be distinct ordered bases for V and let $B_{2}, B_{3}$ be distinct ordered bases for $W$.
>
> Let $M^{2}_{0}(T)$ be the matrix for $T$ with respect to $B_{0}, B_{2}$ and let $M^{3}_{1}(T)$ be the matrix for $T$ with respect to $B_{1}, B_{3}$.
>
> Let $M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})$ be the matrix of the identity map $I_{V}:V \to V$  with respect to $B_{0}, B_{1}$ and let $M^{2}_{3}(I_{W})$ be the matrix of the identity map $I_{W}:W \to W$ with respect to $B_{2}, B_{3}$.
>
> Then $ M^{3}_{1}(T) = M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})M^{2}_{0}(T)M^{0}_{1}(I_{V}) $.

My proof:

Take any  $ v \in V$ and let $w = T(v) \in W$. I write $[v]_{0}, [v]_{1}$ for $v$ expressed in bases$B_{0}, B_{1}$, respectively. Similarly for $[w]_{2}, [w]_{3}$.

The following relations hold:

$1)$ $[v]_{0} = M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})[v]_{1} $

$2)$ $[w]_{3}= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})[w]_{2}$.

It follows that

$ M^{3}_{1}(T)[v]_{1}=[w]_{3}= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})[w]_{2} = M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{0}_{2}(T) [v]_0 =  M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{0}_{2}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})[v]_{1}$.

Since the choice of $v$ was arbitrary, it must be that

$M^{3}_{1}(T)= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{2}_{0}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})$.   $ \blacksquare $

[Added: Essentially I have tried to rewrite the following theorem in a way that is more intuitive to me. Have I succeeded? Is my proof also correct?]

[image: Theorem]

Comment: Nevermind! The proof is correct. Found it in Schaum's outline!

Comment: All you need is for $V_1\stackrel T\rightarrow V_2\stackrel {T'} \rightarrow V_3$ the straightforwardly shown $M_1^3(T'\circ T)=M_2^3(T')M_1^2(T)$. Apply this to $T$ and the identities.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to point few things about your proof:
$a)$ $v$ should be a non-zero vector for the conclusion of the statement $M^{3}_{1}(T)= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{2}_{0}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})$.
$b)$ This statement $ M^{3}_{1}(T)[v]_{1}=[w]_{3}$  doesn't follow from relation $1)$ and $2)$. It should be made an explicit statement.
$c)$ You should take linear transformation $T$ to be a non-zero linear transformation which is inherently assumed in **Theorem $45$.**.

Rest Your Proof works fine for me.

Comment: a) It should be *all* vectors $v$, just like OP stated in the proof. One non-zero vector is not enough, one has to check at least on a basis. b) The statement $M_1^3(T)[v]_1=[w]_3$ holds by definition of $M_1^3(T)$, no need to make it explicit. c) The theorem holds for all $T$ not just non-zero ones.

Comment: @Christoph If $v$ is zero vector, then you won't be able to conclude the following statement: $M^{3}_{1}(T)= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{2}_{0}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})$. Also, I never mentioned that $v$ is a single vector. Please read carefully. Moreover, OP says "It follows",  It means that we can conclude the following statement "$ M^{3}_{1}(T)[v]_{1}=[w]_{3}$" from the previous statements which is viciously false. Further, It's true that Theorem also holds for zero linear transformation (LT) but while proving we assume, that LT is a non-zero as zero LT's doesn't help us to establish the statement.

Comment: Two maps $f,g\colon A\to B$ are equal iff $f(a)=g(a)$ for *all* $a\in A$, the zero vector doesn't need to be excluded. "It follows that" refers to not just the first equality but the complete chain that follows. Proving the statement one doesn't need to assume $T$ is non-zero, it works the same for all $T$ including the zero map.

Comment: @Christoph okay tell me: how will you conclude $M^{3}_{1}(T)= M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{2}_{0}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})$ from $ M^{3}_{1}(T)[v]_{1}=  M^{3}_{2}(I_{W})  M^{0}_{2}(T) M^{0}_{1}(I_{V})[v]_{1}$ if $v$ is a zero vector.? If I think you can provided me a reasonable argument, then I will delete my post. :)

Comment: You can't make that conclusion if $v$ is *a* non-zero vector either. The conclusion is from having equality for *all* vectors $v\in V$.

Comment: @Christoph I have only eliminated a zero vector. I haven't excluded other vectors. So, even if I remove a zero vector, the choices can still be arbitrary.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense and I explained why in details, I won't comment anymore.